# Knex, inserting random columns

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, knex.js

What I am trying to do is use knex's trx in order to post data to my database. When I try to send a post request and process it with the following code I get this error:

> Failing row contains (4, null, , null, 2021-05-13 23:12:17.642)

I don't have much experience with knex so I have no clue why there are two null values in with the three values that are supposed to be there. I feel like this is simple but I can't find anything on it online.

```
const handleAnnouncementCreation = (req, res, db) => {
    const { body } = req.body;
    db.transaction(trx => { 
        trx.insert({
            body: body,
            posted: new Date()
        }).into('news_posts').returning('id').then(id => {
            res.json(id);
        }).then(trx.commit).catch(trx.rollback);
    }).catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to assign a `Json` value (the value of `body`) into a column.

You should use `JSON.stringify` on the body value.

```js
const handleAnnouncementCreation = (req, res, db) => {
  const { body } = req.body;
  db.transaction((trx) => {
    trx
      .insert({
        body: JSON.stringify(body), // <-- 
        posted: new Date(),
      })
      .into('news_posts')
      .returning('id')
      .then((id) => {
        res.json(id);
      })
      .then(trx.commit)
      .catch(trx.rollback);
  }).catch((err) => res.status(400).json(err));
};
```